# SwiftUI Header/Title Text Background Color Screen Wide

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ipad

I want to set the background color for "Sebastian's Favorite Stuff" to encompass the entire area. Currently it looks like this and I want to cover the white spaces.

[image: App Layout]

My Code is as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        GridRow{
            Text("SEBASTIAN'S FAVORITE STUFF")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(10)
                .font(.system(size: 500))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                .colorInvert()
        }
        .background(Color(red: 0.18 , green: 0.59 , blue: 0.65 ))
        HStack{
            ScrollView{
                Grid{
```

What do I need to adjust so it fills the area and not just the text background?

Comment: you could try something like this: `ZStack {
          Color(red: 0.18, green: 0.59, blue: 0.65).ignoresSafeArea()
           VStack { ... `

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Winner winner. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chain `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on the `Text` as the last modifier, the background color should extend to the left and right edges.

Answer (score 1):

A `GridRow` is expected to be a child of a `Grid`. So in this case, I wouldn't use a `GridRow` and just use `Text` by itself.

Then, all you need to do is force the text to use the full width. Since the background will touch the edges of the safe area, it will extend into the safe area too. This is because you are using `background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)` (with round parentheses). The default parameter for `ignoresSafeAreaEdges` is `Edge.Set.all`.

Like this:

```swift
VStack{
    Text("SEBASTIAN'S FAVORITE STUFF") // not nested in a GridRow any more
        .lineLimit(1)
        .padding(10)
        .font(.system(size: 500))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
        .colorInvert()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // added
        .background(Color(red: 0.18 , green: 0.59 , blue: 0.65 ))
    HStack {
        ScrollView {
            Grid{
```

If you want to fill the whole screen background then you could move the background up a level and put it behind the `VStack` instead. The `maxWidth` is no longer needed on the `Text`. It is not needed on the `VStack` either, because the `ScrollView` will force the `VStack` to fill all the space available (a `ScrollView` is greedy).

```swift
VStack{
    Text("SEBASTIAN'S FAVORITE STUFF")
        .lineLimit(1)
        .padding(10)
        .font(.system(size: 500))
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
        .colorInvert()
    HStack {
        // as before
    }
}
.background(Color(red: 0.18 , green: 0.59 , blue: 0.65 ))
```

If that still leaves some gaps then you need to look at the next parent, and so on.